# Wrong query in mariadb

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

what is the problem with this query:

```
INSERT INTO x(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
VALUES (1,
        1,
        "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">Hi</p>\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong>Bye</strong></p>",
        "test",
        "test",
        "test",
        "test")
SELECT *
FROM x,
     y
WHERE `condition`
```

the error message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * FROM
>                          x, y
>                       WHERE
>             ' at line 2
>          at Error (native) code: 1064

Comment: have tried ending the first query with a ;?

Comment: all of this is one query! a conditional insert ... is not it? :S

Comment: no, you can't do a select query appended to the end of an insert. Without knowing what you are trying to do, I can't really answer

Comment: I see there are two queries not one as you say..
The first one is INSERT INTO statement.
The second one is SELECT statement.
for the SELECT statement, I think that you can't get data from TWO TABLES at once without identifying relationship for a field between the two tables.

Comment: i need a conditional INSERT, i searched some and found this syntax...what is the correct way to do this insert?@SaggingRufus

Comment: my x table have 13 columns and i am going to insert into just 7 column of a row that has the condition @Youssef13

Comment: are you sure this isn't an update? I have never heard of a conditional insert.

Comment: @Saeed.At
I couldn't see any problems with the INSERT INTO statement, it just inserts some CONSTANT values which are 1,1,some html code,test,test,test,test to the columns a, b, c, d, e, f, g....

for SELECT statement, As far as I know, You can't get from two tables without a relationship between them.

If you're trying to execute the INSERT INTO & SELECT statements at one time, you can't do that. In such case, Let us know what you want exactly to do.

Comment: yes, i think it is just a simple UPDATE query... :)))) thanks for help@SaggingRufus @Youssef13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you *wanted*.  Here are some tips, from which you should be able to figure out how to fix your code:

This is a valid standalone statement:

```
INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (...);
```

This is an `INSERT` that gets the values from a `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO t (...)
    SELECT ...;
```

This is an old fashioned way to do `FROM` with two tables:

```
SELECT ... FROM x, y WHERE ...;
```

Change to

```
SELECT ...
    FROM x
    JOIN y ON ...
    WHERE ...;
```

Comment: it was a problem with choosing `select`, i had to use `update` query... :))
i thought it is so complex and never think about `update` ...

Comment: See also `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`